# Resize RelativeLayout above Soft Keyboard

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-softkeyboard

I'd like the red `RelativeLayout` to fill the same area as this when the keyboard is opened.

Currently is gets pushed off the screen..

[image]

Here is my code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="TEXT VIEW"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textColor="#171717"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="#ffffff"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:text="EDIT TEXT"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textColor="#171717"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
        android:background="#ffffff"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest is set to `adjustResize`. I have tried `adjustPan` etc..

Answer (score 0):

in your manifest file under activity tag just add:

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustpan|adjustResize"
```

will solve your problem!!

Comment: Nope, adjustResize works the way is should but adjustPan does not help.